# What is the real world use of BeanPostProcessor in spring?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, ioc-container

I am aware of the bean post processor and it's working but I am not sure how it will helps us in real world application. what should be there inside the below define method in real application could it be

```
1 Some configuration Code?
2 Some validation code for bean ?




 public class MyBeanInitProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor{
     
        @Override
        public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
                throws BeansException {
            System.out.println("before initialization: "+beanName);
            return bean;
        }
     
        @Override
        public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
                throws BeansException {
            System.out.println("after initialization: "+beanName);
            return bean;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most real-world applications, you won't be interacting with them directly. [Spring provides 28 implementations out of the box](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html) that handle standard functions like autowiring and applying AOP advice. You use them indirectly by using the standard Spring features such as applying validation annotations on a method parameter, which applies `MethodValidationPostProcessor`, or making method calls `@Async`, which applies `AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`.

Comment: Do you have any such scenario where you have wrote your own post processor ?

Comment: @Monica No. It's a part of the core infrastructure, and I've never needed anything beyond the ones that are already included. What I have done is written various rules, such as AOP interceptors, or validations, that are applied by the existing processors.

Answer (score 0):

BeanPostProcessor is a means of running a bit of code each time a bean is initialized.

- Say you had an algorithm to process an *undetermined* number of Customer objects.
- Say each Customer was a bean, and (as you may find in a LinkedList) each bean could tell if there was a bean following it, or not.
- Say further that you need an event to be thrown when the last bean in that list was initialized.

You could do that, if you added code in postProcessAfterInitialization(). Knowing Spring, there are better ways, no doubt. Still, to me, this would be a case where BeanPostProcessor could be helpful.

Comment: But, how will you find if it is in a list & it is the last entry in list?